# Tsyringe's `resolve` function throws "TypeInfo not known for X" error when using register methods with dependencies

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, tsyringe

I was playing with [Tsyringe](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe). Seems like it works well when I use decorators however I couldn't make it work with [register](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe#register) function.

Here are what I've tried

#### Test 1: OK

Here I simply use `@singleton()` decorator, it **works fine**!

```
@singleton()
class Child1 {}

@singleton()
class Child2 {}

@singleton()
class Parent {
  constructor(public readonly child1: Child1, public readonly child2: Child2) {}
}

const parent = container.resolve(Parent);

expect(parent).toBeInstanceOf(Parent);
expect(parent.child1).toBe(container.resolve(Child1));
expect(parent.child2).toBe(container.resolve(Child2));
```

#### Test 2: ERROR

I expected this to be same as previous one. I register via `registerSingleton` method instead of `@singleton()` decorator. However `container.resolve` throws **TypeInfo not known for "Parent"** error.

```
class Child1 {}
class Child2 {}

class Parent {
  constructor(public readonly child1: Child1, public readonly child2: Child2) {}
}

container.registerSingleton(Child1);
container.registerSingleton(Child2);
container.registerSingleton(Parent);

const parent = container.resolve(Parent);

expect(parent).toBeInstanceOf(Parent);
expect(parent.child1).toBe(container.resolve(Child1));
expect(parent.child2).toBe(container.resolve(Child2));
```

#### Test 3: ERROR

I also expected this to be same as the first one. I register via `register` method instead of `@singleton()` decorator. Again `container.resolve` throws **TypeInfo not known for "Parent"** error.

```
class Child1 {}
class Child2 {}

class Parent {
  constructor(public readonly child1: Child1, public readonly child2: Child2) {}
}

container.register(Child1, { useClass: Child1 }, { lifecycle: Lifecycle.Singleton });
container.register(Child2, { useClass: Child2 }, { lifecycle: Lifecycle.Singleton });
container.register(Parent, { useClass: Parent }, { lifecycle: Lifecycle.Singleton });

const parent = container.resolve(Parent);

expect(parent).toBeInstanceOf(Parent);
expect(parent.child1).toBe(container.resolve(Child1));
expect(parent.child2).toBe(container.resolve(Child2));
```

#### Test 4: OK

Then I removed the constructor arguments and used `register` method. It **worked fine** too.

```
class Parent {}

container.register(Parent, { useClass: Parent }, { lifecycle: Lifecycle.Singleton });

const parent1 = container.resolve(Parent);
const parent2 = container.resolve(Parent);

expect(parent1).toBeInstanceOf(Parent);
expect(parent1).toBe(parent2);
```

## Question

What am I doing wrong in tests 2 and 3?

### Update

I've checked Tsyringe [unit tests](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe/blob/master/src/__tests__/global-container.test.ts). Classes are decorated with either `@injectable()` or `@singleton()` in all cases where a constructor injection is tested.

Then I found that `@injectable()` makes a `typeInfo.set(target, getParamInfo(target));` [call](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe/blob/master/src/decorators/injectable.ts#L13) (also @singleton calls @injectable). As far as I understand, this sets constructor parameters of a decorated class to a global Map called `typeInfo`.  `register` or `registerSingleton` are not making this call. Hence when I try to `resolve` I get a "TypeInfo not found" [error](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe/blob/master/src/dependency-container.ts#L522).

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature.

### Update2

As far as I understand, it is neither a bug nor a feature. It is just a limitation. Constructor parameter type resolution in Tsyringe relies on (I think there is nothing else that it could rely on) "Reflect.getMetadata" which can be used only when you use decorators. Hence, a class' dependencies can only be injected if it is decorated by one of Tysringe's decorators such as `@injectable()`, `@singleton()` etc.